# File Read-Write Error in iOS

Tags: ios, file, exception, unity-game-engine

I have used following code for file reading and writing.

```
 private void StorePuzzleData ()
 {
     FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo (Application.persistentDataPath + "\\" + difficultyLevel + puzzleId + ".txt");

     if (fileInfo.Exists)
         fileInfo.Delete ();

     string fileData = string.Empty;

     foreach (CellInformation cellInfo in cellInfoList)
         fileData += cellInfo.RowIndex + "#" + cellInfo.ColIndex + "#" + cellInfo.number + "#" + cellInfo.CellColor + "#" + cellInfo.CellDisplayColor + "#" + (cellInfo.IsGroupComplete ? 1 : 0) + ",";

     StreamWriter streamWriter = fileInfo.CreateText ();
     streamWriter.WriteLine (fileData);
     streamWriter.Close ();

     DataStorage.StorePuzzleTimePassed (difficultyLevel, puzzleId, GameController.gamePlayTime);

 }

 private void ReadPuzzleData ()
 {
     // format:  rownumber, colnumber, number, cellcolor, celldisplaycolor, isgroupcomplete

     StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText (Application.persistentDataPath + "\\" + difficultyLevel + puzzleId + ".txt");
     string fileData = streamReader.ReadLine ();
 }
```

But I am getting following error in actual iOS device running. This code working correct in iMac as well in android device.

[image]

[image]

Please give me some suggestion what changes I need to do to make this correct.

Comment: the only thing that does not look right is the last slash in your path is a backslash while all others are forwardslashes, try using "//" instead of "\\" everywhere in your code

Comment: Then it will crash on Windows :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're using Windows-style paths in a Unix-like (Apple Mac OS) environment. Notice that on windows you have paths with a backslash like

```
   C:\Users\Maxi\Desktop
```

On Unix-like system however something like

```
  /var/mobile/Containers
```

You notice that in your faulty path you have mixed forward and backward slashes, which makes the path invalid.

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2.....\debutan1.txt
```

The correct way to always generate the correct path is to use the [`Path.Combine(string, string)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Path.Combine.html) function. This will combine two paths using the correct directory path seperator, which can also be seperatly accessed through [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.html).

So, in order to make your code correct, you would do

```
 using System.IO; /* must be imported */

 private void StorePuzzleData ()
 {
     FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo (Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, difficultyLevel + puzzleId + ".txt"));

     if (fileInfo.Exists)
         fileInfo.Delete ();

     string fileData = string.Empty;

     foreach (CellInformation cellInfo in cellInfoList)
         fileData += cellInfo.RowIndex + "#" + cellInfo.ColIndex + "#" + cellInfo.number + "#" + cellInfo.CellColor + "#" + cellInfo.CellDisplayColor + "#" + (cellInfo.IsGroupComplete ? 1 : 0) + ",";

     StreamWriter streamWriter = fileInfo.CreateText ();
     streamWriter.WriteLine (fileData);
     streamWriter.Close ();

     DataStorage.StorePuzzleTimePassed (difficultyLevel, puzzleId, GameController.gamePlayTime);

 }

 private void ReadPuzzleData ()
 {
     // format:  rownumber, colnumber, number, cellcolor, celldisplaycolor, isgroupcomplete

     StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText (Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, difficultyLevel + puzzleId + ".txt"));
     string fileData = streamReader.ReadLine ();
 }
```

If this still gives an "Access denied" error it must be because of filepermissions. Post the output of `ls -la <thatpath>` then.

Comment: Right now I am testing build with this suggestion: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/161526/write-to-iphone-file-system-access-denied.html